# Depicting fast/slow speed of a streak

Tags: path, illustration, critique, drawing, path-effects

I'm designing a scientific illustration where I'd like to show the fastness and slowness of a moving electron. Here in this attached picture, I show the electron path. I want to show that electron slows down when it enters and moves within the highlighted region. Please share if you have any ideas or images from which I can get inspired from.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: what have you tried that didn't turn out to work?

Answer (score 1):

Your image is a static trajectory of an electron. You obviously try to show the route and all places where the electron has been lived a while as a part of some material structure. The three darker areas obviously have something which makes those areas a little more attractive and the electron has been felt the possible landing points in them comfortable a little longer.

Your options to present the speed in the image:

- do not use static image , have an animation
- paint the trajectory with different colors, have a legend what the colors mean

BTW. Think beforehand what to say to the wise guy who tells that he has red something about the possiblity to know the place and the motion state of an electron simultaneously. You can keep his mouth shut by presenting the trajectory in the animation as fuzzy transition and highlighting the whole substructure where the electron lives a while.

Comment: Alternately, the faster parts of the streak could have partial transparency, and one decreases the degree of transparency as the electron's velocity along trajectory slows...